# Check for uppercase and lowercase letters C#

Tags: c#

How can I not check for just uppercase or lowercase letters.

```
if(textBox1.Text == "StackOverFlow")
{
    //Some Code
}
```

If I type stackoverflow it would count it as false. But if it is typed as StackOverFlow the exact word it would be counted as true. Please help.

Comment: From your post, it's not quite clear what you're looking for. Your code already does case-sensitive comparison. Do you want to do a case-insensitive comparison? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(textBox1.Text.ToLowerInvariant() == "stackoverflow")
{
// Some code
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think of that. Thanks!

Comment: Error Output: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: Depending on the requirements (is this a user-supplied string or e.g. part of a file system path?), `ToLowerInvariant()` might be the wrong choice. Casing is culture dependent.

Answer (score 0):

```
"StackOverFlow".Equals(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Use the String.Equals method.

By using StringComparison-Option `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` your two strings will be compared ignoring the casing.

Comment: Returns with highlight: OrdinalIgnoreCase

Comment: Depending on the requirements (is this a user-supplied string or e.g. part of a file system path?), `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` might be correct instead. Casing is culture dependent.